# Texture breaking when painting

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

Not sure what it could be, got it after upgrading to 3.6.1, please help :(

[image: i dont know what it is]

Comment: it should be black

Comment: Hello please share your file

Comment: @moonboots https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vi2F1ffi-u8fDxJSXiRdKc7WeY1DaQeN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You didn't pack your images, for the moment the material is pink

Comment: @moonboots oopsie https://drive.google.com/file/d/16XgqrtPsdgeYcwSVBZYKavmDwplIFc7R/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @moonboots should i modify them in paint.net?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a bug due to the image format.

In the *Image Editor* window, select the image, then *Image > Save As > File Format* > choose *PNG > Save as Image*, then, in the *Image Editor*, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to reload the image. This time the painting will work normally. Pack your images.

Or, if you don't want to pack your images, open them in an image software and convert them to PNG (or JPG, or EXR).